# Coffee draining from conical filter to cylindrical coffee pot

Tags: calculus, geometry

I found the solution to the problem I am working but I don't understand one assumption they make in the solution. Can you please explain?

Here is the question: Coffee is draining from a full conical filter basket into a cylindrical coffee pot at the rate of $10\ in^3$/min. How fast is the level in the pot rising when the height of coffee in the filter is 5in? How fast is the level in the filter cone falling?  (from the picture given: the diameter of the cone top and the cylinder is 6 inches.)

In all the answers found online, [here](http://www.ccsdk12.org/mclemens/courses/APcalcAssign/DA2-4.pdf) and [here](http://www.firelandsschools.org/Downloads/RelatedRates.pdf) for example, and in another cone problem a found in my book a page before, they use the assumption that the radius of the cone is half the height. r=h/2. How can they make that assumption? At least in the problem a page earlier, they stated that assumption.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial for further reference. You could also give a link to the exact question or answers you refer to, in case they offer any hints for why such an assumption was made. :) Good luck.

Comment: I added two links. The viewer will have to scroll to find the coffee question/answer. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The problem states the height and width of the cone are both 6 so $r=h/2$.

Comment: Hi Tomoki, the problem in my book only shows the widths to be 6" and does not show the height being 6" like in the two links I included. In fact, the height of the filter appears to be 5" according to their drawing. However, the answer is the same in both my book and the two links. This leads me to believe there is a r=h/2 relationship I missed.

Comment: @user462582 The question you posted says when the coffee is 5" deep, are you seeing that measurement? The ratio is arbitrary and depends on the cone but will stay constant as the coffee flows out.